# Commutation Relations in Second Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, second-quantization, dirac-delta-distributions

I understand that if I have the field operators $\psi(r)$ and $\psi^\dagger(r)$, then I have the canonical commutation relation (in the boson case) $$[ \psi(r) , \psi^\dagger(r')]=\delta(r-r').$$  My question is that if during manipulation of an equation I want to use the commutator, but both field operators are evaluated at zero, then I have $$[ \psi(0) , \psi^\dagger(0)]=\delta(0).$$
But $\delta(0)$ does not seem to be well defined even under the integral.  I know I'm missing something really simple here.

I suppose my question then is what explicitly is the value of the commutator $[ \psi(0),\psi^\dagger(0)]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything: the commutator $[\psi(0),\psi^\dagger(0)]$ is ill defined. This is related to the fact that operators are actually distributions, not functions of $x$, so taking $x=0$ is meaningless.

Comment: So then I am only allowed to use the commutation relations if $\psi$ is left unevaluated? what then is the meaning of the symbol $\psi(0)$?

Comment: The context of this is that I am dealing with the function $C(x) = <n(x)n(0)>$, where $n(x) = \psi\dagger(x)\psi(x)$, and the brackets denote  an expectation value.

Comment: 1) yes, so to speak. 2) $\psi(0)$  can only be used in formal expressions when it is not multiplied by another factor of $\psi$. For example, $\langle 0|\psi(0)|0\rangle$ is well defined, but $\langle 0|\psi(0)^2|0\rangle$ is not. This is because there is not a well defined notion of multiplication for distributions: $\psi(0)^2$ doesn't make sense. Functions can be multiplied, but distributions cannot. 3) Are you sure that $C(x)=\langle n(x)n(0)\rangle$? shouldn't the fields be normal-ordered? (normal ordering enables us to multiply distributions in a well defined way).

Comment: This was how the problem was posed to me.  The context is that I am dealing with noninteracting spinless fermions in one dimension.

Comment: @PaulMalinowski then I guess the fields should be time-ordered at least (right?). My best bet is that you are supposed to expand $\psi$ in creation/annihilation  operators, where time-ordering is to some extent equivalent to time-ordering because of Wick's theorem. I'd suggest you to expand $\psi(x)$ in $a,a^\dagger$ and see what happens - but if there is no ordering prescription the expression is ill-defined.

Comment: $\langle (\psi (0) \pm \psi^\dagger (0))^2 \rangle =  \infty $ no? This make sense for me. Means that this field has infinite fluctuations at the point 0.

Comment: @Nogueira i guess this is a matter of opinion, but to me it does not make sense. In QFT correlation functions do not measure actual correlations in the statistical sense of the world. "Correlator" is jut terminology, but in fact it has nothing to do with actual correlations nor fluctuations. Therefore, the fact that a correlator blows up at a certain point doesnt mean that the field "fluctuates" there. (Note that "quantum fluctuations" is not a well defined concept anyway)

Comment: Define this field: $X= \psi^{\dagger}+\psi$. Thais field is hermitian, and then an observable in principle. Calculate the statistical fluctuation of this field for the the vaccum state at some point: $\Delta X(x)=\langle X ^2(x)-\langle X (x) \rangle^2 \rangle$. So, this is not a correlation function, is the fluctuation of the field. If you integrate this fluctuations at some volume nas average that, you would find that this fluctuations is infinity but start to be finite and very small ir the mass of the particle os big.

Answer (score 2):

When you write $n(x)=\psi^\dagger(x)\psi(x)$, you basically claim that $n(x)$ is a composite operator. Such naively defined composite operators in QFT suffer from UV-divergences, and this is essentially what you observe. In order to have a well-defined $n(x)$, you need to renormalize it, and the standard approach for free theories is to take a normal-ordered product. For *bilinears* like $n(x)$ this is basically equivalent to shifting $n(x)$ by its (infinite) vacuum expectation value,
$$
n_R(x)=n(x)-\langle n(x) \rangle.
$$
For more general operators you need to use more complicated formulas (you will know which when you know what is normal-ordering). In interacting theories the definition of composite operators is more intricate and generally subject to ambiguities.