# How to normalize the states in the continuous limit?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, second-quantization, normalization

In quantum field theories we can perform the continuous limit, where we take the limit $V\rightarrow\infty$ for the volume system. In quantum optics, we can start by absorbing a factor $\left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{3/2}$, see for example [this script](https://www.matthiaspospiech.de/files/studium/skripte/QOscript.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, right before (2.64). We can define the new plane wave operators:

$$ b_{\vec{k}} := \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{3/2} a_{\vec{k}} \tag{1} $$

The commutator of the new operators is

$$  [b_{\vec{k}}, b_{\vec{k}'}] = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{3} \delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'} \tag{2} $$

where in the continuous limit, $\left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{3/2} 
\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}\rightarrow\delta(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')$. Of course, the operators $b_{\vec{k}}$ are then only defined in a distributional sense, since from (1) the operator would "blow up" if $L\rightarrow\infty$. Similarly, the commutator of an operator with its hermitian conjugate equals $\delta(0)$, which is also not well-defined, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/250475/). Nevertheless, all of this makes sense if we write down the equations for a finite volume and take the limit at the end and so it makes sense to treat these as distributions.

But there is one thing missing here and I also cannot find it in the script linked above. How are the states now normalized?

In the finite case, the Fock states are orthonormal:

$$ \langle n_1, n_2, ... | n_1', n_2', ... \rangle = \delta_{n_1,n_1'} \delta_{n_2,n_2'} ... \tag{3} $$

but this becomes problematic in the finite case where the $b$ operators now have some dimensionality attached to them.

Let's consider the expression

$$ \langle n_\vec{k} | a_\vec{k}^\dagger a_\vec{k} | n_\vec{k} \rangle = n_\vec{k} = \bar{\langle n_\vec{k} |} b_\vec{k}^\dagger b_\vec{k} \bar{| n_\vec{k} \rangle} \tag{4}$$

wher the operators with the bar are the renormalized operators for $b$ to act on.
It becomes clear that to preserve the right hand side, the states for $b$ have to be normalized so that

$$ \bar{\langle n_{\vec{k}} }|\bar{n_\vec{k} \rangle} = \left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)^{3} \tag{6}$$

How is this replacement done formally? Can I just set up a new normalization rule because I now want to operate with different operators?

Also, this is not consistent with the fact that

$$ \bar{\langle n_{\vec{k}} }|\bar{n_{\vec{k}'} \rangle} = \delta(\vec{k}-\vec{k}') \tag{7}$$

should hold in the continuous limit because the states as defined in (6) disappear in the continuous limit (which is equally as bad).

(How) Can I consistently define these states (even if only in a distributional sense) so that this works with the continuous limit?

### Update

Another important result from quantum optics is

$$ |n_k\rangle = \frac{\left(a_k^\dagger\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|0\rangle $$

which would of course imply that the dimensionality of the state changes with $n_k$.

### References:

<sup>1</sup>Maciej Lewenstein *et al.*, *Quantum Optics an Introduction*, (University of Hannover, Germany, July 21, 2006)

Comment: Why don't you consider $\langle \bar n_k|\bar n_{k^\prime}\rangle$ in (4) instead?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Then the left hand side would just equal 1, wouldn't it?

Comment: Trying to understand your question: would you be happy with an axiomatic definition of states in continuum QFT? Or are you looking into a sort of "smooth" transition between IR-regularized states and QFT states?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I think the latter would be more helpful

Comment: I don't understand. the LHS would be $n_k \delta_{kk^\prime}$, no?

Comment: @TobiasFünke In the discrete case (what is it in the continuous case, that is part of the question), the states are normalized to unity $\langle n_\vec{k} | n_\vec{k} \rangle = 1$ or $\langle n_\vec{k} | n_{\vec{k}'} \rangle = \delta_{\vec{k}\vec{k}'}$. Or do you mean keeping the LHS as is and considering $\langle \bar{n_k} | \bar{n_k'} \rangle$ on the RHS? Then I don't see why they should equal at all.

Comment: That the math is fighting you here is probably a good indication that the mental model of "states" is not a very good one (not even on non-relativistic QM but certainly not in QFT). Phenomenologically we are not observing states to begin with but scattering. Unfortunately even scattering does not allow for a consistent plane wave state description in interacting theories because the universe becomes completely opaque for the smallest amount of interaction as soon as we go to V→∞. In other words... an IR cutoff (finite interaction volume) is necessary to talk about actual phenomenology.

Answer (score 1):

Representation theory has a peculiar property of having discontinuities at otherwise well behaved limits.

Think for example the Weyl algebra from QM (exponentiated CCR): for finite $\hbar$, its only unitary irrep is, by Stone-von Neumann theorem, square-integrable wavefunctions over say the coordinate variable $x$.

What happens if we let $\hbar \rightarrow 0$?

Well, for any finite $\hbar$ the stone-von Neumann theorem works. But for $\hbar = 0$ it completely falls apart:

1. The CCR/Weyl algebra becomes commutative, which means all its irreps are 1-dimensional (as opposed to acting on the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space). These are values of the observable at particular phase space points, and there's now an uncountable infinity of them.
2. The representation obtained by following the wavefunction representation over the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit is completely unphysical: in fact, it has $p \psi(x) = - i \hbar \psi'(x) = 0$, so it corresponds to some direct sum / integral of $(x, 0)$ phase space points. It completely ignores all the other, $p \neq 0$ phase space points.

One may wonder: what happened to the classical limit of QM, is it somehow anomalous?

It isn't. If you use the right language, the limit is smooth; it's just that the language of wavefunctions isn't the right language to describe the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit.

A similar thing happens in your case. Note that the CCR algebra changes when you decompactify a finite-volume system. While the $V \rightarrow \infty$ limit looks continuous in the algebraic language, it has representation theoretic discontinuities.